# Creating call accounting table with ROW_NUMBER() and CASE statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create some reports from some raw data on a phone system.   This system has call coming in from multiple locations that may or may not be answered and data may also have several rows between an call request, answer, and hangup.  Ultimately I'd like a row with call request, start, end (simplified below) times for each call.   Origin and Destination will also be included but were left out of the simplified query

I've tried creating the row numbers and various versions or the below with the hope creating the single row but the variation in the row numbers in the join is where I am having issues overcoming. [END].RowNumber = (START.RowNumber-1 )

```
WITH CallRowNum AS
(
    SELECT (CASE WHEN Text LIKE 'Call request from%' THEN (LogTime) 
                 ELSE NULL 
            END) AS REQUEST_TIME,
           (CASE WHEN Text LIKE 'Start conversation%' THEN (LogTime) 
                 ELSE NULL 
            END) AS CALL_START,
           (CASE WHEN Text LIKE 'Call deleted%'  THEN (LogTime) 
                 ELSE NULL 
            END) AS CallEnd,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (REQUEST_TIME,CALL_START, CALL_END)) AS RowNumber
    FROM [LogEntry] LE
)
  SELECT *
  FROM (Select * 
        FROM CallRowNum 
        WHERE [CALL START] IS NOT NULL) START
        JOIN (SELECT * 
              FROM CallRowNum 
              WHERE [CallEnd] IS NOT NULL)  [END] 
          ON [END].RowNumber = (START.RowNumber-1)
  WHERE (START.[CALL START] IS NOT NULL  
     OR START.[CALL_REQUEST] IS NOT NULL 
     OR START.CallEnd IS NOT NULL)
```

so far I'm unable to get a join to have the proper call request, start and end time.   The above is just for tying the start and end piece

EDIT -  SAMPLE DATA:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: IDEAL RESULTS WOULD BE SIMILAR TO ROW: ORIGIN, DESTINATION, CALL REQUEST, CALL START, CALL END,   I would then add calculated columns to determine talk time, ring time, etc.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Show the table LogEntry with sample data. You would need to do more than sort on time, since you could have this bee the order of events:[req1,req2,callstart1,callstart2,callend2,callend1]. As far as I can see you would need to sort on phone, and logtime [req1,callstart1,callend1], [req2,callstart2,callend2], or some other identifier.